# Magento 2 : Online Customer is Not Showing in Admin

Tags: magento-2.1, admin, customer, grid

I am using Magento-2.1 as back-end and frontend are made in angular. If I disable Magento frontend using some extension, Online Customer is not showing in Magento admin panel. Please suggest me any solution what I do?

Comment: anybody help me.